# node.js vs IIS 7.5 performance

Tags: linux, performance, node.js, iis

### The setup:

2 machines on EC2 of type m3.xlarge.

First one with ubuntu server.

Second one win2008r2.

node.js on ubuntu using the basic example to return a string response to any request.

asp.net httphandler to return the same response.

using https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns 
I used 10 machines to execute 200000 with concurrency of 2000 (200 per machine)
I ran the benchmark and got:

### NodeJS:

```
 Complete requests:         200000

 Requests per second:       5605.170000 [#/sec] (mean)

 Time per request:          358.071900 [ms] (mean)

 50% response time:         31.000000 [ms] (mean)

 90% response time:         239.300000 [ms] (mean)
```

### IIS:

```
 Complete requests:         200000

 Requests per second:       9263.810000 [#/sec] (mean)

 Time per request:          215.992900 [ms] (mean)

 50% response time:         214.000000 [ms] (mean)

 90% response time:         244.000000 [ms] (mean)
```

The nodeJS code is:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Some response\n');
}).listen(80);
```

The httphandler code is:

```
context.Response.Write("Some response\n" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
```

I thought node js will be much faster, did I do something wrong?

### EDIT:

after using the cluster module I got 16685 request per second from the node js
I"m going to bring up the strongest EC2 instances and check on them

Comment: IMHO the only bad in your example is that you took axiomatically that nodeJS runs the fastest no matter what. NodeJS is faster under very specific conditions. With nodeJS you should also mind the hosting platform that supports the ecosystem (Don't forget it's single threaded).

Comment: Node.js is fast at I/O. I see no I/O in this benchmark. It's like calculating fibonacci. Of course it's going to be faster in C(#).

Comment: I don't think this is a question. It also has a misleading title, since IIS no longer "wins" when compared to multiple node threads. How about deleting this off SO and moving it to a blog post?

Comment: This is a toy app. You need to test a workload that resembles what you want to put into production.

Comment: Did you use three workers, or four?

Answer (score 1):

An m3.xlarge instance has a few cpu cores, whereas node.js is single-threaded. You can try to benchmark the [node.js cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) and see if using more CPU's helps. And, since node.js is quite new, make sure to use the latest stable series (0.8.x at the time of writing this).

Comment: I used the latest version 0.8.14 I'll try the cluster module and post the results